# perl redirect url with the paramter using $Std->url()

Tags: perl, url, redirect, mason

I am new to Perl/Mason.
My url is `https://www.myurl.com/myPar/2016image` which will return a png image.

In this url, `myPar` is the parameter (equals to `$orderViewHelper->{orderId}`).

I have created an `orderViewHelper` which will hold `myImage` object so I can access it in other classes. Is there a way that I can use `$Std->url()` to get the image and put it into myImage?

```
$orderViewHelper->{myImage} = $Std->url(
  'https://www.myurl.com/$orderViewHelper->{orderId}/2016image',
  { absolute =>1 }
);
```

Comment: so you are saying that `$orderViewHelper->{myImage}` doesn't hold your image object after assigning an image object, Could you please check `print Dumper($orderViewHelper->{myImage});`, What does this return?

Comment: @AbhiNickz     is this a correct way to put a paramter inside a url https://www.myurl.com/$orderViewHelper->{orderId} /2016image .The paramter is "$orderViewHelper->{orderId}".

Comment: ohh, You are using perl '' single quote instead of "" double quote so interpolation of `$orderViewHelper->{orderId}` is not happneing, sorry I didn't see it first. I think this will fix everything: `$orderViewHelper->{myImage} = $Std->url("https://www.myurl.com/$orderViewHelper->{orderId}/2016image",
                                            {   absolute =>1
                                            });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
$orderViewHelper->{myImage} = $Std->url("https://www.myurl.com/$orderViewHelper->{orderId}/2016image", { absolute =>1 });
```